# How to set raster layer name inside raster::calc function

Tags: raster, r

I'm using `raster::calc` to make some calculations and write the output to GeoTiff in just one go. But I'd like to set the layer name of the output before writing to disk. I'm trying to do this by using `setNames` inside the function but it's now working. How can I change layer name inside a `raster::calc` call that saves the file to disk?

Here is a simple reprex

```r
library(raster)
#> Loading required package: sp

r <- raster(ncols=36, nrows=18)
r[] <- 1:ncell(r)
names(r) <- 'my_name_is'

r2 <- calc(r, function(x) {
    y <- x * 10
    y <- setNames(y, 'my_name_is')
})

names(r2)
#> [1] "layer"
```

<sup>Created on 2020-05-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Great! Thanks for the info. I was getting confused because when I opened the created TIFF in R, it used the filename as the layer name. If you post the comment as an answer, I'd mark it as accepted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not necessary. The only place the name will be retained is in the raster object, which is a pointer to the on disk raster. If you close your session and read the raster into a new session, the names will not be there. The tiff format does not store layer names like a format such as img. If you just want to write a tiff with a specific name you can use the filename argument in `calc`.